# Slow disk reads on RHEL 5.3

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, redhat

I recently installed RHEL 5.3 on my desktop from Ubuntu and I'm getting some extremely slow disk reads and I haven't been able to fix the problem. I'm using a Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 ST3250820AS but only getting ~3.6 MB/sec reads. I haven't been able to set DMA using hdparm. Any suggestions on how to get better read speed out of this?

```
# hdparm -Tt /dev/hda
/dev/hda:
 Timing cached reads:   16380 MB in  2.00 seconds = 8209.75 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   12 MB in  3.04 seconds =   3.94 MB/sec
```

I'm pretty sure the multcount is wrong as well.

```
# hdparm /dev/hda
    /dev/hda:
     multcount    = 16 (on)
     IO_support   =  0 (default 16-bit)
     unmaskirq    =  0 (off)
     using_dma    =  0 (off)
     keepsettings =  0 (off)
     readonly     =  0 (off)
     readahead    = 256 (on)
     geometry     = 30401/255/63, sectors = 488397168, start = 0
```

The current Kernel I'm on.

```
# uname -a
Linux novaprospekt 2.6.18-128.1.6.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 24 12:10:27 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How old is the hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

One question to ask: what kind of disk controller are you on? If you're on an old, lousy ATA/33 controller that doesn't support DMA (very well), doesn't do 32-bit I/O, and so on, you're pretty limited in terms of what you can do.

Answer (score 2):

> using_dma    =  0 (off)

This is a big problem. When you run the tests, do you notice a high cpu spike?

Try providing the output of hdparm -i /dev/hda; and see what might cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, how are writes?

```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=fil1 bs=1M count=2000
```